# What is the default user/pass for Fedora 35 ARM images?

Tags: fedora, login, arm

I cannot find the default **user/pass** for **Fedora 35 ARM aarch64** anywhere on the web. I downloaded the image from here: https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora-secondary/releases/35/Spins/aarch64/images/Fedora-Minimal-35-1.2.aarch64.raw.xz

Comment: There is no default password. If you've installed it, you should have specified the credentials. If you are using it as a live image, you may use an empty password if it asks for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ mashuptwice is right; there is no default password. However I installed this on a Raspberry Pi 4 compute module, and when it booted, it came to a menu with options to set a user/root password/timezone. But stupidly, it also gives you the option to 'quit'. when you quit it just goes to a boot prompt asking for a username/password. There is no fix for this, no way to get back to that setup menu, so it has to be reinstalled at that point. It's a terribly flawed design.